# Program to synchronize data and schema in two SQL server 2005 database

Tags: sql-server, compare, database-schema

I need a software that let me compare and synchronize two database on two different server.
I found [this](http://www.sqldelta.com/), and was great until i deploy the site and put the database online.
Now I can't connect to remote server.
The standard port of SQL server is opened to my IP.

1. Anyone use it?
2. Do I miss something?
3. Does anyone know a better software?

I've tried to get support but after 5 days still no answer on the forum.
Please, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/) offer some very good tools for this.

There's:
[Red Gate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index-2.htm)
[Red Gate Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

For schema management (versioning, continuous integration & automated migrations) you can try [Wizardby](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-wizardby/).

It allows you to apply migrations to multiple database instances in a controlled and consistent manner.

Answer (score 0):

It's a guess, but the most likely cause of your problem seems to me to be that the synchronisation process has amended either the password or the permissions of the login you are using to connect to your remote site. It's impossible to know without more details of exactly what you did with sqldelta.

Try using a username/password combination which works on your local machine. If this doesn't work, you will probably need to request some help from the DBA of the remote machine, either to recreate your original login or restore the database to a pre-synchronisation state.

I'm not sure that this is down to the tool - it would be possible to do this with any of the database comparison tools for SQL server which include permission/login synchronisation.